# Mi código solo imprime los 10 primeros elementos de 140

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import json
import datetime   

with open('/Users/kenyacastellanos/Downloads/data.json') as json_data_file:
    data = json.load(json_data_file)

data['activities'].sort(key = lambda x: x['user_id'])

for x in range(len('activities')):
    print("New Order:", data['activities'][:])

    date1 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(data['activities'][x]['answered_at'])
    date2 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(data['activities'][x]['first_seen_at'])
    difference_date = (date1-date2)
    print("Duration in seconds:", difference_date.seconds, difference_date.microseconds)
```

El programa está diseñado para leer un json, acomodarlo por 'user_id' y calcular la duración de la sesión (answered_at - first_seen_at) en segundos; solo imprime los 10 primeros elementos pero necesito que imprima todos los que están en 'activities' que son 140. Antes de añadir el `for x in range` solo imprimía uno.
También, la duración se imprime aparte y necesito que se imprima junto con la demás información en 'activities'.

Esto es lo que contiene 'activities'. (No están los 140, no cabía en el cuerpo de la pregunta)

```
{
   "activities":[
      {
         "id":272961,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:09:53.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:09:40.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":402616,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:10:27.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:10:09.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":64828,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:13:19.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:13:03.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":397256,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:18:06.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:17:47.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":202872,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:19:00.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:18:54.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":367396,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:23:30.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:23:18.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":378117,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:25:12.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:25:05.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":119374,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:36:27.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:36:08.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":360744,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T03:26:25.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T03:26:19.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":99644,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T03:28:03.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T03:27:51.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":257563,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T03:32:13.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T03:31:55.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":85196,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T03:36:43.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T03:36:30.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":116202,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T03:38:30.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T03:38:11.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":61200,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T03:41:18.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T03:41:13.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":404661,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T03:14:24.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T03:14:09.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":203564,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T03:15:13.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T03:14:56.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":247269,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T03:18:48.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T03:18:37.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":106898,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T03:20:17.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T03:19:59.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":221951,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T03:25:53.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T03:25:45.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":160830,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T23:56:20.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T23:56:11.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":361518,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T23:58:00.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T23:57:43.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":224039,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:00:12.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:00:01.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":181539,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:01:23.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:01:07.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":253744,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:02:32.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:02:22.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":161490,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:07:14.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:06:59.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":226347,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:11:26.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:11:09.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":174067,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:13:23.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:13:15.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":351811,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:14:33.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:14:21.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":233660,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:15:32.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:15:18.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":495862,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:16:28.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:16:10.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":138862,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:17:30.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:17:10.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":164425,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T00:18:37.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T00:18:30.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":105977,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T09:38:47.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T09:38:40.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":309376,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T09:40:18.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T09:40:06.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":305887,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T09:43:20.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T09:43:01.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":32758,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T09:45:46.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T09:45:40.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":444810,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T09:50:15.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T09:50:01.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":270759,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T09:53:13.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T09:53:07.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":56294,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T09:54:54.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T09:54:47.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":474939,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T09:56:21.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T09:56:16.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":195074,
         "user_id":"4cviplp",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T09:56:56.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T09:56:37.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":331372,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T08:13:26.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T08:13:15.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":413158,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T08:15:05.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T08:14:59.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":120426,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T08:19:44.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T08:19:27.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":385359,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T08:24:47.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T08:24:39.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":44177,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T08:25:31.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T08:25:18.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":55724,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T08:30:05.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T08:29:55.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":318975,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T08:33:38.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T08:33:22.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":361609,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T08:36:44.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T08:36:31.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":369573,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T08:37:26.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T08:37:07.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":53768,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T08:38:13.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T08:37:59.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":306162,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T02:46:48.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T02:46:32.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":329762,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T02:49:01.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T02:48:45.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":62055,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T02:52:52.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T02:52:35.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":152394,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T02:54:33.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T02:54:22.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":310783,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T02:57:58.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T02:57:52.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":333493,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T02:58:38.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T02:58:18.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":304529,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T02:59:00.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T02:58:55.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":36110,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T02:59:45.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T02:59:27.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":315505,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-20T03:01:30.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-20T03:01:24.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":464523,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T16:24:04.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T16:23:50.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":383193,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T16:25:16.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T16:25:02.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":73686,
         "user_id":"oiy0r57s",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T16:26:06.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T16:25:59.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":59566,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-15T04:23:17.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-15T04:23:09.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":52417,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-15T04:27:59.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-15T04:27:51.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":103123,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-15T04:28:43.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-15T04:28:31.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":230014,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-15T04:31:29.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-15T04:31:10.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":479500,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-15T04:35:55.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-15T04:35:40.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":203685,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-15T04:37:23.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-15T04:37:03.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":282664,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-15T04:39:00.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-15T04:38:55.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":200514,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:34:25.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:34:06.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":257863,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:37:58.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:37:46.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":358145,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:39:42.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:39:36.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":380525,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:40:17.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:40:03.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":248135,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:41:47.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:41:42.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":217400,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:42:18.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:42:08.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":144464,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:44:50.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:44:33.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":449170,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:48:00.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:47:53.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":395160,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:50:02.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:49:52.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":354423,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:53:42.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:53:33.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":224633,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T16:55:54.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T16:55:40.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":250453,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T14:13:47.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T14:13:39.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":242991,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T14:14:36.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T14:14:22.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":156743,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T14:18:59.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T14:18:47.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":186501,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T14:23:57.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T14:23:47.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":406667,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T14:26:09.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T14:25:53.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":145790,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T14:27:52.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T14:27:37.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":461933,
         "user_id":"wi6zweox",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T14:28:25.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T14:28:14.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":201530,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T17:31:44.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T17:31:29.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":236626,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T17:33:33.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T17:33:20.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":179536,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T17:37:07.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T17:36:59.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":465047,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T17:39:01.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T17:38:49.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":133911,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T17:43:38.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T17:43:23.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":439680,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-16T17:47:42.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-16T17:47:24.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":451569,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T16:49:01.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T16:48:47.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":386277,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T16:54:10.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T16:53:53.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":152909,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T16:57:38.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T16:57:23.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":421935,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-22T14:06:32.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-22T14:06:17.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":113920,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-22T14:09:18.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-22T14:09:02.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":374924,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-22T14:12:07.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-22T14:11:58.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":239975,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-22T14:12:38.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-22T14:12:33.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":180453,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-22T14:15:56.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-22T14:15:47.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":335543,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-22T14:20:42.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-22T14:20:36.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":188125,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-22T14:24:34.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-22T14:24:24.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":284608,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-22T14:28:55.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-22T14:28:47.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":130339,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-22T14:33:22.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-22T14:33:10.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":37956,
         "user_id":"wipacvrh",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-22T14:33:38.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-22T14:33:32.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":47986,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-14T22:29:43.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-14T22:29:29.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":168254,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-14T22:34:38.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-14T22:34:24.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":411580,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-14T22:36:26.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-14T22:36:16.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":221155,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-14T22:36:59.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-14T22:36:46.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":213166,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-17T08:46:46.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-17T08:46:35.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":351007,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-17T08:49:10.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-17T08:48:56.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":373586,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-17T08:50:41.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-17T08:50:30.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":405419,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-17T08:52:10.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-17T08:51:58.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":493293,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-17T08:53:30.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-17T08:53:17.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":65475,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-17T08:57:19.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-17T08:57:05.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":421014,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-17T08:57:53.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-17T08:57:47.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":236814,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-17T08:58:51.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-17T08:58:45.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":483435,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-17T08:59:55.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-17T08:59:47.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":474141,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T22:36:26.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T22:36:13.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":399672,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T22:39:33.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T22:39:19.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":49602,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T22:40:14.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T22:40:07.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":493418,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T22:44:41.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T22:44:36.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":420879,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T22:45:46.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T22:45:26.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":385504,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T22:50:13.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T22:50:06.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":428470,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T22:52:44.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T22:52:38.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":197715,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-18T22:55:42.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-18T22:55:27.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":310184,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T03:10:59.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T03:10:40.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":460619,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T03:12:47.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T03:12:28.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":218948,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T03:14:07.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T03:13:56.831+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":329188,
         "user_id":"hq0l86xe",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-21T03:32:11.831+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-21T03:31:53.831+00:00"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Cual es el resultado de `range(len('activities'))`

Comment: me parece que `len('activities')` retorna 10 y `range(10)` retornara `10` o me equivoco? XD

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent claramente el error proviene de ahí, el resultado de eso es 10. Lo correcto debe ser `range(len(data["activities"]))`

Comment: déjame agregarle la respuesta entonces @Christian

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent ok, aunque el problema es solo un error tipográfico y ya vote por su cierre

Comment: Sí, en efecto retorna 10.

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos, ya lo corregí! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de lógica, estas implementando incorrectamente:

```
for x in range(len('activities')):
```

cuando debe de ser:

```
for x in range(len(data['activities'])):
```

Cuando implementas Json tienes que asegurarte de que estas accediendo al dato del objeto y no usando su índice contextualmente.

Comment: Si, lo acabo de corregir y ya los imprime todos. Muchas gracias! 

Comment: @Kenncd de nada para eso estamos ...

Comment: @Kenncd si tu pregunta fue resuelta puedes marcarlas de esa manera.